# TreeView manipulation, saving adding etc

Tags: asp.net, treeview, viewstate

Here is what I am trying to do. I have a TreeView server side control (asp.net 2.0) and I need the user to be able to add nodes to it, then after all the nodes desired are added, the data should be saved to the database.

Here are some things I would like to pay attention to:

1) I don't want to save the tree data each time the new node is added, but rather keep the data in session until the user decides to save the entire tree. The question here is: can I bind the tree to ArrayList object and keep that object in session (rather than keeping the whole tree in session)? Then each time the node is added I will have to rebind the tree to the ArrayList rather than database.

2) I wish to minimize ViewState, any tips? What works best: compressing viewstate or keeping it all on the server at all times?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use TreeNodeCollection as your internal array to hold in either ViewState or Session. Here's a rough mock-up of an approach you can use; far from perfect, but should set you on the right track.

```
TreeView tv = new TreeView();
    // Button click event for 'Add Node' button
    protected void AddNode(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (SaveNodeToDb(txtNewNode.Text, txtNavUrl.Text))
        {
            // Store user input details for new node in Session
            Nodes.Add(new TreeNode() { Text = txtNewNode.Text, NavigateUrl = txtNavUrl.Text });
            // Clear and re-add
            tv.Nodes.Clear();
            foreach (TreeNode n in Nodes)
                tv.Nodes.Add(n);
        }

    }

    public bool SaveNodeToDb(string name, string url)
    {
        // DB save action here.
    }

    public TreeNodeCollection Nodes
    {
        get
        {
            if (Session["UserNodes"] ! = null)
                return (TreeNodeCollection) Session["UserNodes"];
            else
                return new TreeNodeCollection();
        }
        set
        {
            Session["UserNodes"] = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Btw, if you want to do Array manipulation first, then just seperate off that DB save into a seperate button click event.